# getElement by class not ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to target not by selecting an ID but a class as I have few menus. The working code with id is the following:

```
new SVGDDMenu( document.getElementById( 'menu' ) );
```

I have tried:

```
new SVGDDMenu( $(".menus"));
```

and

```
new SVGDDMenu(".menus");
```

Also tried

```
new SVGDDMenu( document.getElementsByClassName('CLASS NAME'));
```

This is the full code which works with ID:

```
        (function() {

            function SVGDDMenu( el, options ) {
                this.el = el;
                this.init();
            }

            SVGDDMenu.prototype.init = function() {
                this.shapeEl = this.el.querySelector( 'div.morph-shape' );

                var s = Snap( this.shapeEl.querySelector( 'svg' ) );
                this.pathEl = s.select( 'path' );
                this.paths = {
                    reset : this.pathEl.attr( 'd' ),
                    open : this.shapeEl.getAttribute( 'data-morph-open' )
                };

                this.isOpen = false;

                this.initEvents();
            };

            SVGDDMenu.prototype.initEvents = function() {
                this.el.addEventListener( 'click', this.toggle.bind(this) );

                // For Demo purposes only
                [].slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll('a') ).forEach( function(el) {
                    el.onclick = function() { return false; }
                } );
            };

            SVGDDMenu.prototype.toggle = function() {
                var self = this;

                if( this.isOpen ) {
                    classie.remove( self.el, 'menu--open' );
                }
                else {
                    classie.add( self.el, 'menu--open' );
                }

                this.pathEl.stop().animate( { 'path' : this.paths.open }, 320, mina.easeinout, function() {
                    self.pathEl.stop().animate( { 'path' : self.paths.reset }, 1000, mina.elastic );
                } );

                this.isOpen = !this.isOpen; 
            };

            new SVGDDMenu( document.getElementById( 'menu' ) );

        })();
```

[And the plugIn I am using is here](http://tympanus.net/Development/ElasticSVGElements/dropdown.html)

Comment: What is SVGDDMenu ? Could you give to us link to the plugin ?

Comment: Just updated the question with the link. Thanks

Comment: Any reason why I am getting down votes?

Comment: presumably the function expects a single element as argument, not jQuery objects or arrays of elements

Comment: @charlietfl see the accepted answers and the comments below that

Comment: can't blame the plugin docs for not knowing how the DOM API works when you query for elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('name')` returns an array.  You need to select from that array to return an element. Ex. `document.getElementsByClassName('name')[0]`

Assuming that your class name selector is correct, and you choose the right array index, and you're not using an old version of IE, this should work.

Comment: I see. It works. Didn't know about it was giving an array. Thanks a lot. Will accept it.

Comment: Read the doc, apparently it works since IE9, which I am good with it

Comment: Actually, it returns an array-like object that is called an `HTMLCollection` or `NodeList`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: the doc didn't say about the array see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for that @Xotic750

Comment: Yea, sometimes it's best to just play around in console to see what's going on.  It says it returns an HTMLCollection as @Xotic750 pointed out, not an array.  But it acts like an array.